# How do you delete a sub-string in a string(qstring) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Is there a function in Qt similar to delete() and copy() in Delphi.

I am reading data from a device connected to my computer via USB and storing it as a `QString`. Every line that is read is not the same (or is cut short, even while using readyRead). I created a buffer sting to add these "half sting" (eg. string = "This" instead of "This is a string#") to and now I want to copy the string up until the '#' and then delete the string so if new "half stings" get added I can do the same with them. The code below is what I tried

```
void MainWindow::readSerial()
{
    QByteArray serialData = port->readAll();
    serialBuffer += serialData;

    QByteArray serialString = serialBuffer.

    qDebug() << serialString;
    ui -> textEdit ->append(serialString);

    //serialBuffer.replace(serialString,"");
}
```

The above code only returns an empty string.

Comment: The `QString::operator+=` function have [an overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-2b-eq-6) for `QByteArray`. There no need for the `toStdString` and `fromStdString`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it and it works but I still need a way to copy a certain part of a string and then delete that part

Comment: I suggest you keep the data as QByteArray for as long as you can. Only convert to QString when you need QString. Also, always use an explicit encoding for any external data (eg  from file or network) instead of trusting the default to be always correct.

Comment: Especially if data is Utf8, individual unicode characters may get split between reads, so in that case you *must* keep your read buffer as bytes, and decode to QString only once you have entire line (or what ever other way of knowing you won't have split utf8 chars).

Comment: Which  methods can be used to read the vallues between the '$' and "\r\n" in the following string : "$GNRMC,161500.00,A,2503.00987,S,02824.47892,E,0.230,,210919,,,A*7D\r\n$GNRMC," end then delete the part that was read sothat the new string is:"$GNRMC,"

Comment: I changed the QStings to QByteArray. Thanks hyde!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::readSerial()
{
    QByteArray serialData = port->readAll();
    serialBuffer += serialData;

    QString serialString = serialBuffer.mid(serialBuffer.indexOf("$"),serialBuffer.indexOf("\r\n"));

    qDebug()<< "index of \r\n" << serialBuffer.indexOf("\r\n");
    qDebug() << "SerialString" <<serialString;
    ui -> textEdit ->append(serialString);
    qDebug() << "SerialBuffer: " << serialBuffer;

    serialBuffer.replace(serialString + "\r\n","");

}
```

the above code works. Thanks all.

regards

Comment: Even if answering your own question, please try to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would help others having the same or similar problem as you to know more details about what you did.